# Uploading a large volume of documents with metadata

Tags: 2013, records-management, records-center, file-metadata

I have a requirement to upload thousands of documents to SharePoint with metadata - probably using .csv that points to file location on a hard disk with the relevant metadata and destination library.

Is anyone aware of an existing solution that can handle such a process, or would it need to be custom developed?

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact requirement in a project where we had to upload 50k documents with metadata. There is no existing solution to handle this.

We had written a Windows forms application which handled upload of CSV file containing the records and did the upload batch by batch (typically 1000 docs at a time) using CSOM as we didn't have access to the server at that time and we used to leave it running overnight. Not too hard to accomplish this. Would just take a little time for the operation to finish.

**Update:**
Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f135715cb2a7846795b1

Comment: Might you be able to do a high-level explanation of the CSOM solution you came up with to handle the process?

Comment: @ITDGood check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create the desired folder structure in a document library as well as the desired columns. Then in the document library settings, configure default values for the folders, setting the desired values in that folder.

Upload the files to the respective folders (manually or via script) and they will pick up the default metadata values.

This also has the benefit of new files being added after the migration will get the default values.

It is a balance between structure and metadata to find what yo are looking for.